# Is PhoneGap only for NativeApplications or for remote web app HTML pages too?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap I want to know whether PhoneGap is only for Native Applications or for remote web app HTML pages too. Please any one answer me.

Thank you Lakshmi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Phonegap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap)! enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3, instead of lower-level languages such as Objective-C/core-java. The resulting applications are hybrid, meaning that they are neither truly native (all layout rendering is done via the webview instead of the platform's native UI framework) nor purely web based (they are not just web apps but packed for appstore distribution, and have access to part of the device application programming interface).  You can try [Sencha, Ext-JS HTML5](http://www.sencha.com/)! frameworks to create remote web app HTML pages.

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)! enables a web developer access to mobile devices's phonebook, Geolocation, compass, accelerometer,etc.(A browser is not exposed to these APIs')

[Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)! is another platform for developing mobile, tablet and desktop applications using web technologies.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap can be used on webapps too, if loaded through PhoneGap. It won't work in mobile safari directly, you must also open the site via PhoneGap (the app on iDevices)

Answer (score 1):

The power of Phonegap is that you can build apps with web technologies and then package them to install as native apps from the app stores. To the user there is no differentiation between a pure native app and a phonegap app. The average user just sees an "app" that they are used to. If you're going to build a vanilla mobile website, you won't have access to the native libraries which is what Phonegap is intended to leverage.